# Adding Selected Text into a Textbox separated by a comma

Tags: c#

I currently have this code, what it does is from another form i select genres
and the selected genres will be placed in a textbox when ok is pressed
this is the code for the OK button:

But i have an issue
When i am in the genre's form and i select 3 at the same time for example 
Action & Adventure, Comedy, Drama it writes them well in the text box
but when i open the form again and select another genre and press ok, then it will show like this:
Action & Adventure,, Comedy
and if i select another it will add 2 commas after comedy

```
    private void OkayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Temp = "";
        foreach (string Genre in SelectedGenresList)

        {

            Temp += Genre + ", ";

        }

        SelectedGenres = Temp;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: After your `foreach` loop, try adding this: `Temp = Temp.Trim().TrimEnd(',');`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked

Answer (score 1):

add the selected genre to a list. than you can easily "merge" the entries to a string with delimiter.
example:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "John", "Anna", "Monica" };
var result = String.Join(", ", names.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the example